# Как разобраться с экраном

Tags: android, java

Дайте пожалуйста четкий ответ. Вот в Андроид есть плотность экранов. ldpi mdpi hdpi xhdpi xxhdpi.

1. Какой изначально должен быть размер картинки чтобы она на всех экранах отображалась одинаково
2. Какой утилитой или сервисом или сайтом воспользоваться чтобы разделить эту картинку под каждую плотность, так чтобы она на всех экранах одинаково отображалась?

Comment: А что такое одинаково?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ну я тоже задавался этим вопросом, и не найдя никакого ПО в интернете, решил сделать своё. Т.к. картинки обязан предоставлять **заказчик**, то программу я эту сильно **не развивал**.

[вот прога](https://github.com/argamidon/ImageScale)

правила такие:

- воспринимает только .png файлы
- выбираете картинку первой кнопкой
- выбираете местоположение папки `res` проекта. это обязательно указать папку которая называется `res`.
- вводите размер картинки, который должен лежать в папке medium, 50х50 например;
- отмечаете галочками папки в которые нужно положить картинку.

Answer (score 0):

Пользуйтесь официальными гайдами [screen support](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html) и [multiscreen](http://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/screensizes.html). В Android Studio есть возможность просмотра экрана на различных устройствах. В вкладке peview вашего layout выберете Preview All Screen Sizes.

Answer (score 0):

Достаточно положить картинку в папку с самой большой плотностью (xxxhdpi, или xhdpi), и она сама проскейлится на всех меньших плотностях. Можно делать и в обратном порядке (положить в mdpi, и она проскалится до xxhdpi), но качество проскейленого изображения будет оставлять желать лучшего.  
Проблемы в таком подходе могут если вы используете 9-patch-drawable (*.9.png) изображения.

Так же приложение будет несколько медленнее работать (по крайней мере в теории), т. к. системе придется скейлить изображения (не факт, но мне почему-то так кажется)